# how to get input array value by key with javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Here is sample code i try to create input array with key and on change i want to get the value of individual input array value.

```
<input type="text" name="items[1]" value="443" onchange="get_items(1)">
<input type="text" name="items[2]" value="233" onchange="get_items(2)">
<script>
       function get_items(key)
        {
          alert($("items["+key+"]").val());
        }

</script>
```

Comment: There are multiple typos here. Are they in your demo or real code? Also your selector is wrong

Comment: may it help! [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/gvuk7k6x/#&togetherjs=ykHoPNwtz7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply pass `this` context as argument and get value.

```html
<input type="text" name="items[1]" value="443" onchange="get_items(this)">
<input type="text" name="items[2]" value="233" onchange="get_items(this)">
<script>
  function get_items(ele) {
    alert(ele.value);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Why not forget about passing anything and just use `event.target`?

Answer (score 0):

- Your HTML is missing a closing quote for the `name` attributes.
- The `name` attribute should not contain `[` or `]`
  characters. Adding these characters will complicate matters.
- You should hook up your event handlers in JavaScript, not HTML.
- When practical, elements should have unique `id` attributes added to them, which will make accessing and identifying them much easier in JavaScript and CSS

Rather than trying to identify the textboxes with indexes, just gather them up and place them into an array or array-like container, where indexes will be automatically assigned to them.

Here is a working example of how to get values by index:

```js
// This will scan the DOM and place all matched elements into a node list
// which is an array-like object
var textBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");

// Or, you can get references to them individually:
var txt1 = document.getElementById("txt1");
var txt2 = document.getElementById("txt2");

// And, put them into an array on your own:
var ary = [txt1, txt2];

// No matter how you got your references to them, it's best to hook
// them up to event handler in JavaScript, not HTML
txt1.addEventListener("change", get_items2);
txt2.addEventListener("change", get_items2);

function get_items(key) {
  // You can certainly pass a key to this function
  // to identify which element you are talking about
  alert(textBoxes[key].value);
  
}

function get_items2(evt) {
  // But, event handlers are automatically passed
  // a reference to the object that fired the event
  alert(evt.target.value);
  
}

get_items(0);  // Call the function to get first textbox value
get_items(1);  // Call the function to get second textbox value
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="txt1" value="443">
<input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt2" value="233">
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/gvuk7k6x/#&togetherjs=ykHoPNwtz7)

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="items[1]" value="443" onchange="get_items(1)">
<input type="text" name="items[2]" value="233" onchange="get_items(2)">
```

JS:

```
function get_items(key)
        {
          alert($('input[name="items['+key+']"]').val());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the event's target from `event`,

```js
function get_items(e) {
   console.log(e.target.value); 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="items[1]" value="443" onchange="get_items(event)">
<input type="text" name="items[2]" value="233" onchange="get_items(event)">
```

or, better, attach your listener in javascript:

```js
function get_items(e) {
   console.log(e.target.value); 
};

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

for (var i = 0, el; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
  el = inputs[i]
  el.addEventListener("change", get_items);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" name="items[1]" value="443">
<input type="text" name="items[2]" value="233">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that does what (I think) you are trying to do:

```
<input type="text" name="item1" value="443" onchange="javascript:get_items(1)">
<input type="text" name="item2" value="233" onchange="javascript:get_items(2)">
<script>
    function get_items(key)
    {
        //alert($("items["+key+"]").val());
        var input = $('input[name="item' + key + '"]');
        var value = input.val();
        alert(value);
    }
</script>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9kvv2q7p/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
function get_items(key) {
    alert($("input[name='items[" + key + "]']").val());
}
```

I hope I was helpfull